# Trying to Fatch Firebase URL in Webview PDF but something is wrong

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to give the path to Drive.google.com to fetch data from Firebase but something is wrong with this in try

```
try {
        MainActivity.list.get(position).getPdfUrl() = URLEncoder.encode(MainActivity.list.get(position).getPdfUrl(),"UTF-8"); // error is here
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+MainActivity.list.get(position).getPdfUrl());

}
```

AND the error is

required: variable
found:    value

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG3lE.png)

Comment: As per the error, I think that on the left-hand side it should be a variable like `pdfUrl` or something. But you're providing a function `getPdfUrl()` which is causing the error. Please try using a variable instead of a function on the left side.

Comment: this is not working i try the process you told